# existence of a function that is continuous at every rational and discontinuous at every irrational

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Thomae's function 
gives the existance of a function continuous at every irrational number and discontinuous at every rational number.
Is there existance of a function that is  continuous at every rational and discontinuous at every irrational

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia knows the answer to that. Read "Follow-up" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function